# SID history and file share

Tags: active-directory, access-control-list, share

Several years ago we had like 20k users migrated from different domains to one. The same happened with all the servers (including file share). Now we have one domain, but I'm wondering how exactly ACL is migrated/preserved in such scenario:

1. User A from domain A has access to file share server A
2. User A and file share A are migrated to domain B (SID History enabled)

Does this mean that SID in SID history for user A will allow user to access this file share? Or will this access be "migrated" with the server so user will have access regardles of SID history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I found and what I tested it seems that SDDL migrated from source server to destination is not changed, so the user will keep the access to file share but based on sid history.